# Can't display Azure web sites in VS2013 server explorer

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

When I try to expand the list of Azure web sites in Visual Studio 2013 server explorer, it keeps saying (Refreshing...) and nothing ever happens.

[image: VS2013 Server Explorer]

If I try to right click and pick "Create New Site" I get this error in a message box.

[image]

The other features in the Azure Server Explorer works as intended. It is only the Web Sites tab that gives me this issue.

I'm on Visual Studio Premium 2013 with Update 3 installed.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to why this is happening?

Comment: After installing Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 the issue are gone.